# Can we handle Raise Application error in adf managed beans

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

i am using Raise Application Error in trigger. Error which is raised by raised application error, in JSF it shows a long statement like JBO exception number etc. i want to catch the error in bean an then use a script to display it.

Answer (score 0):

**How to create a custom error handler in ADF :**

1. Create a class that inherit the ADF DCErrorHandlerImpl Class :

   ```
   public class CustomErrorHandler extends DCErrorHandlerImpl {

      List<ExceptionMapper> exceptionMapperList = new ArrayList<ExceptionMapper>();

   public CustomErrorHandler() {
       super(false);
   }

   @Override
   public void reportException(DCBindingContainer dCBindingContainer, Exception exception) {
       this.logException(exception);
   }

   private void logException(Exception exception) {
       if (exception != null) {
           //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT WITH THE EXCEPTION, DISPLAY IT / LOG IT ETC...
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. Specify at the top of your databinding.cpx file to use this custom error handler and not the default one :

   < Application xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adfm/application" ClientType="Generic" ErrorHandlerClass="YOUR_PACKAGE.CustomErrorHandler" Package="view" SeparateXMLFiles="false" id="DataBindings" version="11.1.2.61.83" >